# How to debug Mobile QQ Browser in desktop chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

I want to debug any webpage running in QQ browser of any mobile device in desktop chrome.

Comment: is this what you need? https://blog.campvanilla.com/debug-website-on-mobile-device-5c27c8809d39

Answer (score 0):

not sure why but its not working on chrome, no browser unless you open the chrome browser it self.